# having large .cs files lowering the performance

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, c#-4.0, clearcase-remote-client

I have 100 and above in my cs files in my cs project file , and it is very slow even if i type some namespace or class name in the visual studio editor it is taking around 3 to 4 seconds to respond. Can any one help me on this i cannot remove the cs files from my project is there any workaround for this. 
Thanks in advance
PS: May be this can help i am using clear case as my source control will that effect the performance of the visual studio .(My version of visual studio 2010 express edition)

Comment: 100 isn't many. Are you using any add-ins? If so, what is it like if you disable them all?

Comment: Push the ["turbo" button](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turbo_button) of your computer. More seriously, 3rd party add-ons can be very high resource consumer. Especially ones that performs continuous job (compile, unit test, etc.) like Resharper and similar. Also please descrive the edition of VS you are using, the add-ons you installed, the hardware you are working on, etc.

Comment: Start - Programs - Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 - Visual Studio Tools - Visual Studio Command Prompt (2010).  Type, without quotes "devenv /resetskippkgs" and if that doesn't work, "devenv /safemode".  If latter works, you have an errant extension causing problems.  It could also be anti-virus, you should exclude devenv.exe.

Comment: As mentionned above, make sure it's not an anti-virus/software firewall that sucking ressources. Bring up the Task Manager and sort processes by CPU time and start typing in VS to validate that it's DEVENV.EXE that taking more CPU cycles.

Comment: @MatthewWatson its actually more than 100 files... in some of the projects there are more i thought having large files may be a problem if its not what can be the problem how can i resolve it. i am using visual studio 2010 express edition and i don't have any add- ins for that

Comment: @SteveB I have a laptop and i dont know it has turbo button .. if that is the case the project with less files should also give the same problem but i have other projects which are having 20 cs files they are not this much slow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must be using a lot of unnecessary references in your project. Just go to the references section and delete those extra references.

Comment: Yes, i have done that but of no use. Some where i have seen having large number of partial classes can  lower the performance due to background build that happens automatically and i have disabled that too (The number of files are increasing in this project now and we will have to see the workaround for this issue. all of them are partial classes) Can any help on this issue ?

Answer (score 0):

There should be no problem with large/many .cs files. I have also solutions with 20 projects, some of these projects have many many files and some of these files have 2k - 5k lines of code. And I've no problem typing new code, there is no noticeable delay.
Perhaps it's only because of slow hardware?

Comment: but with the same hardware i am running other projects without any delays. I have clear case as my source control will that impact anything

Comment: Be warned - project count is a large factor in compile and startup times. With .net it cannot be avoided often.